# How to display multiple post in single blade by using two row(example starting post, expired_date post)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a category page and in this I want to display two types of box in single page, one is `starting_post` and `old_post` or `expired`. How can divide a single page in two part?

```
class FrontendController extends Controller
{
    public function welcome()
    {

        // @TODO Refactor This Line
        return view('welcome')

            ->with('title', Setting::first()->site_name)
            ->with('levels', Category::take(7)->get())

            ->with('levels', Category::take(7)->get())
            ->with('first_post', Post::orderBy('created_at','asc')->first())
            ->with('second_post', Post::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->skip(1)->take(1)->get()->first())
            ->with('third_post', Post::orderBy('created_at','asc')->skip(2)->take(2)->get()->first())
            ->with('forth_post', Post::orderBy('created_at','asc')->skip(3)->take(3)->get()->first())
            ->with('HOME', Category::find(1))
            ->with('ABOUT US', Category::find(2))
            ->with('RESEARCH', Category::find(3))
            ->with('NEWS AND PUBLICATION', Category::find(4))
            ->with('EVENTS', Category::find(5))
            ->with('PEOPLE', Category::find(6))
            ->with('CONTACT US',Category::find(7));
    }

    public function singlePost($slug)
    {
        $post=Post::whereSlug($slug)->first();

        return view('single')->with('post', $post)
                       ->with('content', $post)
                       ->with('levels', Category::take(7)->get());
    }

    public function category($slug)
    {
       $category=Category::whereSlug($slug)->firstOrFail();

       return view($category->getTemplateFile())->with('category', $category)
                     ->with('title',$category->name)
                     ->with('levels', Category::take(7)->get());

    }

    public function events($slug)
    {
       $post = Post::where('slug', $slug)->first();

       $coming_events = Post::where('id', '>', $post->id)->desc('id');
       $past_events = Post::where('id', '<', $post->id)->asc('id');

       return view('events_blade')
                ->with('post', $post)
                ->with('categories', Category::take(7)->get())
                ->with('next', Post::find($coming_events))
                ->with('prev', Post::find($past_events));
    }
}
```

**// View | blade**

```
<div class="entry-meta">
<span>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($post->date_time)->format('F j, Y') }}</span> 
<div>
<h class="entry-title">
{{ $post->title }}</h3> 
<div class="entry-content">
   <a target="_blank" href="{{ asset("$post->
      file") }}">
      <p style="font-size: 18px;color: #468b10;"> {{ $post->content }}</p>
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Better to include your view > blade file as well... also specify for which method you would like to create the view.

Comment: I have already created the view blade but when trying to do display post in category it's not working   upcoming events<div class="entry-meta">
                                                <span>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($post->date_time)->format('F j, Y')  }}</span>
     <div><h class="entry-title">{{ $post->title }}</h3>
   <div class="entry-content">  <a  target="_blank" href="{{ asset("$post->file") }}"><p style="font-size: 18px;color: #468b10;">   {{ $post->content }}</p></a>
                                            </div> then past events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your events function like this. Issue with your query builder and you are incorrect setting values for view.

```
public function events($slug)
{
   $post = Post::where('slug', $slug)->first();

   $coming_events = Post::where('id', '>', $post->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
   $past_events = Post::where('id', '<', $post->id)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();

   return view('events_blade')
            ->with('post', $post)
            ->with('categories', Category::take(7)->get())
            ->with('coming_events', $coming_events)
            ->with('past_events', $past_events);
}
```

And inside the `events_blade.blade.php` loop on these two variables separetly.

```
// show upcoming events.

@foreach($coming_events as $ce)
  <div class="entry-meta">
  ...
  <h3> {{ $ce->title }}</h3> 
  ...
  </div>
@endforeach




// show past events.

@foreach($past_events as $pe)
  <div class="entry-meta">
  ...
  <h3> {{ $pe->title }}</h3> 
  ...
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Check the laravel documentation to setting values for blade for more details.

Comment: Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @user10927970 better to share the complete code with question.

Comment: Also the debugging part would be your call... as if any variable suppoted missing or any other debuging needed... you should have to take care this.

Comment: @user10927970 please share the complete code for `events_blade.blade.php`

Comment: 3rd part> </div>
                                        <h3 class="entry-title">{{ $post->title }}</h3>
          <div class="entry-content">
                          <a  target="_blank" href="{{ asset("$post->file") }}"><p style="font-size: 18px;color: #468b10;">   {{ $post->content }}</p></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                       </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                         <div class="feature-post">
                                        @if ($post->featured)

Comment: @user10927970 you can paste here https://pastebin.com/ and send me the generated link else you can also include the complete file content in your question... by editing this.

Comment: https://github.com/me10071990/new-file, is this one also i have, AND here for post controller https://pastebin.com/NHHdWcqb, for frontend controller https://pastebin.com/2TcY6eR3, for view-https://pastebin.com/Vne6RK0f

Comment: @user10927970 change `$category->$coming_events->posts`  to `$coming_events` at line no.16 https://pastebin.com/Vne6RK0f does this work?

Comment: Thanks Vikash, still has same issue ::Undefined variable: coming_events. Even I have defined that

Comment: Use `$coming_events`  not `coming_events`

Comment: I have made EventController and another route Route::get('/category/events/{slug}', 'EventController@index'); and function in eventcontroller and also changed in frontendcontroller, and after that I am getting data , but all in start_post even I set the data will be consider as a old after 7 days and will goes to end_post.... class EventController extends Controller
{
    public function index($slug)
    {$post=Post::where('slug',   $slug)->first();

Comment: Reaminain code ::  $new_post=Post::where('date_time', '<', Carbon::now())->orderBy('date_time', 'asc')->get(); $old_post=Post::where('date_time', '>', Carbon::now())->orderBy('date_time', 'desc')->get();   return view('layouts.categories.events_blade')   ->with('post', $post)   ->with('levels', Category::take(7)->get())  ->with('events_blade',Category::find(7))  ->with('new_post', Post::find($new_post))  ->with('old_post', Post::find($old_post));

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public function events($slug)
    {
       $post = Post::where('slug', $slug)->first();

       $data['coming_events'] = Post::where('id', '>', $post->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
       $data['past_events'] = Post::where('id', '<', $post->id)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();

       return view('events_blade', $data)

    }



<div class="row">

   <div class="col-sm-4">
     <i>current events</i>
     @foreach($coming_events as $new)

           {{ $new->title}}

     @endforeach

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">

    <i>Past events</i>
     @foreach($past_events as $old)

           {{ $old->title}}

     @endforeach

    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: make sure you return this as is:  return view('events_blade', $data)

Comment: yes, returning the same in my frontend conrtoller, even all code that you suggested I tried

Comment: i checked the spelling all over

Answer (score 0):

then you have to do it this way:

```
public function events($slug)
{
       $post= Post::where('slug', $slug)->first();
       $data['post'] = Post::where('slug', $slug)->first();

       $data['coming_events'] = Post::where('id', '>', $post->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
       $data['past_events'] = Post::where('id', '<', $post->id)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();

       data['categories']=Category::take(7)->get();

       return view('events_blade', $data)
}
```